# problem initializing required resources for rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every one, I am trying to install rgbdslam in ubuntu 12.10 and groovy ros. I tried to set the "ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" and I am getting this error: "Missing resource rgbdslam_freiburg"
I have downloaded rgbdslam which is now in "/home/rgbdslam"
can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57711/problem-initializing-required-resources-for-rgbdslam/) by [hossein_dolat@yahoo.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/4394/hossein_dolat@yahoo.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having ros packages in /home/ is not how it's meant to be, they should be somewhere in a subdirectory of your home folder, e.g. under /home//ros

I suggest you follow these [instructions for installing rgbdslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#RGB-D_SLAM_for_.22Not-yet.22_ROS_Users)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0